# Need libquadmath source code but cannot find

Tags: cross-compiling, hdf5

I am trying to cross compile hdf5 for aarch64-linux (I built a gcc (v. 9.5.0) cross-compiler for aarch64-linux), but have an issue where the configure script is indicating I have an incompatible libquadmath.so file (the configure script is using the one for x86_64).  As such I searched for libquadmath source code but can not find it. If I have libquadmath source code, then I can cross compile it for aarch64-linux.  Please let me know.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I found that libquadmath is in the GCC tree.  Regardless, I have gone a different direction so this is no longer relevant for me.  Apologies for taking up any forum time.